# ng repeat on click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm working on the customized multiselection field according to my client's requirement. Now I have implemented a filter for the ng-repeat linked to the text box. By typing some text ng-repeat triggers and filtered values respectively to the typed alphabet, it should appear in the div. Now the tough part is, on click of a arrow button I need all the ng-repeated list should be appeared without a filter applied to it. So that user can select any list item manually without being alphabet specific.

Comment: Code code code. Show some.

Comment: Without code ... what do you expect us to understand ? Have you done some work or expecting magic results ?

Answer (score -1):

I think you need a box where you can select one item from list which will filter on typing, Please try to use https://ghiden.github.io/angucomplete-alt which is Autocomplete Directive for AngularJS